# Convert from two's complement into unsigned number

Tags: binary

> There is an 8-bit numerical value, where a negative number is
>   represented in two’s  complement. When this value is represented in
>   decimal, it becomes -100. When  this value is regarded as an unsigned
>   number, which of the following is the correct  value in decimal?

First, I have to calculate the decimal 100 in binary, and add the signed bit at the start :

> **1**110 0100

Then, to get the non-negative decimal value of the object, I convert the two complement back to its original value :

> **0**001 1100

which gives me the result is **28**

But the correct answer is `156`, this is the value I will get if I did not replace the MSB (1) with (0) when converting the two complement back to the original value

> **1**001 1100

What am I missing here?

Comment: The 2's compliment representation of -100 is 1001 1100 and not 1110 0100

Comment: @ParthThakkar You are right, I misunderstood the question, so silly of me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First consider the decimal number 100. Binary notation of 100 would be

> 01100100

Applying the two's complement, we find that -100 must be

> 10011011 + 00000001 = 10011100

Assuming now this is unsigned, we get $128+16+8+4=156$